# how to represent in a line chart, binary data from another column in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, linechart, binary-data

I have this df and I have created a line chart for every unique id . For every separate date, there is a different value in the column Values. And there is a 1 or o in the Bin column. I was wondering if I can represent the dots in the line chart that correspond to 1 value with another colour. thank you in advance

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F1", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", 
"F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
"F4", "F4", "F4", "F4"), Date = c("22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "22/6/2021", 
"23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", 
"28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", 
"30/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", 
"26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021"), Values = c(9.6, 
9.8, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.1, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 6556, 3405, 3410, 3980, 5567, 
59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, 54, 61, 53.6), Bin = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

this is the line chart

```
lst1 <- df %>% 
  group_split(grp =((match(ID, unique(ID)) -1) %/% 1 + 1))

ggplot(aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values)) +       
             geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point() + 
             facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `color`-argument:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(Bin))) + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')
```

returns

[image]